# Form_for Error: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an app that features workouts models, each workout `has_many` exercises, and each exercise `has_many` reports.

My routes are as follows:

```
        workouts GET    /workouts(.:format)                    workouts#index
                 POST   /workouts(.:format)                    workouts#create
     new_workout GET    /workouts/new(.:format)                workouts#new
    edit_workout GET    /workouts/:id/edit(.:format)           workouts#edit
         workout GET    /workouts/:id(.:format)                workouts#show
                 PATCH  /workouts/:id(.:format)                workouts#update
                 PUT    /workouts/:id(.:format)                workouts#update
                 DELETE /workouts/:id(.:format)                workouts#destroy
       exercises GET    /exercises(.:format)                   exercises#index
                 POST   /exercises(.:format)                   exercises#create
    new_exercise GET    /exercises/new(.:format)               exercises#new
   edit_exercise GET    /exercises/:id/edit(.:format)          exercises#edit
        exercise GET    /exercises/:id(.:format)               exercises#show
                 PATCH  /exercises/:id(.:format)               exercises#update
                 PUT    /exercises/:id(.:format)               exercises#update
                 DELETE /exercises/:id(.:format)               exercises#destroy
         reports POST   /reports(.:format)                     reports#create
          report DELETE /reports/:id(.:format)                 reports#destroy
```

I toyed with nesting the routes, but it caused more problems than it solved, so they remain like this:

```
  resources :workouts
  resources :exercises
  resources :reports, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

On my `workouts#show` page I have a link to add exercises to that workout:

```
<%= link_to 'Add/Edit Exercises', exercises_path(@workout) %>
```

When I click the link, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

When I click the link, it SHOULD go to my `exercises#index` page:

```
<h1>Current Exercises:</h1>
  <% @exercises.each do |exercise| %>
    <p><%= exercise.name %> (<%= link_to "Delete #{exercise.name}", exercise_path(exercise), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>)</p>
  <% end %>
<h1>Add New Exercises:</h1>
  <%= render 'exercises/form' %>
```

It is on the `exercises/_form.html.erb` that the error is being called, on the indicated line:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1">
    <%= form_for @exercise,
        :url => { :controller => "exercises",
        :action => :create,
        :workout_id => @workout.id } do |f| %> <!-- error called on this line -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter exercise name" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_seconds, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_seconds, class: 'check_box' %> Report seconds?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_reps, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_reps, class: 'check_box' %> Report reps?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_weight, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_weight, class: 'check_box' %> Report weight?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center"><%= f.submit "Create Exercise", class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>

    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any insight as to what is causing this error?  Here's my workouts controller:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all
  end

  def show
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @exercise = Exercise.new
    @report = Report.new
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    @workout.user_id = current_user
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.new(workout_params)
    @workout.user = current_user

    if @workout.save
      flash[:notice] = "Workout was saved successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating workout. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @workout.user_id = current_user
  end

  def update
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])

    @workout.name = params[:workout][:name]
    @workout.workout_type = params[:workout][:workout_type]
    @workout.teaser = params[:workout][:teaser]
    @workout.description = params[:workout][:description]
    @workout.video = params[:workout][:video]
    @workout.difficulty = params[:workout][:difficulty]
    @workout.trainer = params[:workout][:trainer]
    @workout.user_id = params[:workout][:user_id]

    if @workout.save
       flash[:notice] = "Workout was updated successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving workout. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])

    if @workout.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@workout.name}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the workout."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private
  def workout_params
    params.require(:workout).permit(:name, :workout_type, :teaser, :description, :video, :difficulty, :trainer, :user_id)
  end
end
```

And here's the exercises controller:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def index
    @exercises = Exercise.all
  end

  def new
    @exercise = Exercise.new
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.new(exercise_params)
    exercise.user = current_user

    if exercise.save
      flash[:notice] = "Results saved successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Results failed to save."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.find(params[:id])

    if exercise.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Exercise was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Exercise couldn't be deleted. Try again."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  private

  def exercise_params
    params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :needs_seconds, :needs_weight, :needs_reps)
  end

  def authorize_user
    exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user == current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have permission to create or delete an exercise."
      redirect_to [exercise.workout]
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the server log:

```
Started GET "/exercises.abs-0002" for ::1 at 2016-06-01 13:10:33 -0700
Processing by ExercisesController#index as 
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Workout Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "workouts".* FROM "workouts" WHERE "workouts"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Exercise Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises"
  Rendered exercises/_form.html.erb (9.6ms)
  Rendered exercises/index.html.erb within layouts/application (18.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/exercises/_form.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_exercises__form_html_erb___1550785662008061170_70245396037240'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:202:in `with_output_buffer'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:444:in `form_for'
  app/views/exercises/_form.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_exercises__form_html_erb___1550785662008061170_70245396037240'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
  app/views/exercises/index.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_exercises_index_html_erb___2271140629366515446_70245347113980'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/elizabethbayardelle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  meta-tags (2.1.0) lib/meta_tags/controller_helper.rb:26:in `render_with_meta_tags'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:14:in `render_with_remotipart'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `link_to` in `workouts#show` can be like below:

```
<%= link_to 'Add/Edit Exercises', exercises_path(workout_id: @workout.id) %>
```

**exercises_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @workout = Workout.find_by_id(params[:workout_id])
    @exercise = Exercise.new
    @exercises = Exercise.all
end
```

You can pass the **workout_id** in hidden field of `exercises/_form.html.erb` as follows:

```
<%= form_for @exercise do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :workout_id, @workout.id %>
<% end %>
```

And, include `workout_id` to your strong param as follows:

```
def exercise_params
    params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :needs_seconds, :needs_weight, :needs_reps, :workout_id)
end
```

Comment: Still getting a `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` on the workout_id line of the `exercises/_form.html.erb`

Comment: Just try to `puts @workout.id` in `exercises/_form.html.erb` and see what does it return to you .

Comment: @Liz you can pass workout_id in params using hidden_field. Check the updated answer.

Comment: It still gave me a `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass` on `<%= @workout.id %>`

Comment: Still getting `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass` on the `hidden_field` line

Comment: @Liz can you post your server log when you click on **Add/Edit Exercises** link ? This error is occurring because `id` is being called on a **Nil** object i.e **@workout is Nil** here.

Comment: I added the server log in an edit to the original post.

Comment: @Liz `Started GET "/exercises.abs-0002"` - This is where the issue lies. I think here your `workout id` is **abs-0002** which should be in a query string format like `Started GET "/exercises?workout_id=abs-0002"`. Not sure why it is not generating the correct url for you. Hence, your `params[:workout_id]` returns **nil** and you get the error.